# Is it possible to pass an objects function to a buttons onClick event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> This is the HTML

```
<form class='frm1'>
                <h2>Enter Loan Amount:</h2>
                <input type='text' name='Lamount' id='Lamount'>
                
                <h2>Enter Credit Score:</h2>
                <input type='text' name='Cscore' id='Cscore'><!-- comment -->
                
                <h2>Enter Estimated Property Taxes:</h2>
                <input type='text' name='Ptaxes' id='Ptaxes'><!-- comment -->
                
                <h2>Enter Estimated Monthly Mortgage Insurance:</h2>
                <input type='text' name='Minsurance' id='Minsurance'><!-- comment -->
                
                <h2>How many years will this loan be active?:</h2>
                <input type='text' name='Yactive' id='Yactive'>
                <br><br>
                
                <button id='btn1' onClick="loanCalculator.getIR()">Continue</button>
```

> I tried using just the getIR() and it still didnt do what it is supposed to.
>
> I've also tried wrapping the object in a function called getIR and storing the values inside of an array but when I tried alerting or writing the contents of the array all that printed was "object"

```
            </form>
```

> This is the Javascript

```
loanCalculator = {
        loan_amt: document.getElementById('Lamount').value,
        c_score: document.getElementById('Cscore').value,
        p_taxes: document.getElementById('Ptaxes').value,
        m_insurance: document.getElementById('Minsurance').value,
        y_active: document.getElementById('Yactive').value,
        getIR: function(){
            if(c_score <= 500){
                alert("5% Interest Rate");
            }
            else if(c_score >=501 && c_score <600){
                alert("4.75% Interest Rate");
            }
            else if(c_score >=601 && c_score <700){
                alert("4.45% Interest Rate");
            }
            else{
                alert("4.25% Interest Rate");
            }
        }



    };
```

Comment: `c_score` is not defined within `getIR`. Should be `loanCalculator.c_score`

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples is as follows.

```js
loanCalculator = {
  getIR: function() {
    const c_score = parseInt(document.getElementById('Cscore').value)
    if (c_score <= 500) {
      alert("5% Interest Rate");
    } else if (c_score >= 501 && c_score < 600) {
      alert("4.75% Interest Rate");
    } else if (c_score >= 601 && c_score < 700) {
      alert("4.45% Interest Rate");
    } else {
      alert("4.25% Interest Rate");
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<h2>Enter Credit Score:</h2>
<input type='text' name='Cscore' id='Cscore'><!-- comment -->
<button id='btn1' onClick="loanCalculator.getIR()">Continue</button>
```

You need to execute `document.getElementById(xxx).value` every time after the button is clicked, so I guess you may don't need
`c_score: document.getElementById('Cscore').value`.
(This is off topic but please be careful about validation of input values.)